# ggplot multiple line charts with reshape2 melt() - ignoring NA/empty in the chart

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a Milestone Trend Analysis with R. At some point, a Milestone is reached and will not be reported anymore. That's also when the line in the graph should stop. So I tried to implement this with ggplot and reshape2 to melt the dataset in a long format:

**#edit** (Data model by code, sorry)
Datamodel:
[image: Datamodel "MTA_data"]

```
MTA_data<- data.frame(ReportingDates = c("01.01.2021", "01.02.2021", 
                                          "01.03.2021", "01.04.2021", "01.05.2021", "01.06.2021", "01.07.2021", 
                                          "01.08.2021", "01.09.2021", "01.10.2021", "01.11.2021", "01.12.2021"),
                       Milestone1 = c("01.02.2021", "01.03.2021", NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       Milestone2 = c("01.06.2021", "01.06.2021","01.06.2021", "01.06.2021", "01.07.2021",
                                      "01.07.2021", NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       Milestone3 = c("01.09.2021", "01.09.2021", "01.09.2021", "01.09.2021", "01.09.2021",
                                      "01.09.2021", "01.09.2021", "01.11.2021", "01.11.2021", "01.11.2021",
                                      "01.11.2021", NA),
                       MilestoneDates = c("01.01.2021","01.02.2021", "01.03.2021", "01.04.2021", "01.05.2021", "01.06.2021",
                                          "01.07.2021", "01.08.2021", "01.09.2021", "01.10.2021", "01.11.2021","01.12.2021"))

dput(MTA_data)
```

---

#code for meld and plot:

```
MTA_data.long <-melt(MTA_data,id.vars = "ReportingDates")
x <- ggplot(MTA_data.long, aes(ReportingDates,value,color=variable))+
              geom_line(data=MTA_data.long, aes(x=ReportingDates, y=value, group=variable))+
              geom_point()

x
```

---

result:
[image: ggplot chart with N/A]

Well, since some milestones don't have a planning date anymore at some reporting date (milestone is reached), the value is NA or empty (doesn't matter, the issue remains the same). Is there a way to make ggplot ignoring the NA/empty this way so that the lines will stop at this points?

expected result:
[image: MTA Chart]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll need to create grouping variables indicating which groups of points are connected or not. Or maybe filter the data... not sure. (Seems like your two pictures are identical??) For help with that, please share some sample data in a copy/pasteable format---we can't run code on a screenshot. `dput()` is a great way to create copy/pasteable versions of data including class and structure info, e.g., `dput(MTA_data.long[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. Choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas sorry, I made an issue with the screenshots.. should be fine now and also I provided the copy pastable code data hopefully. Would very appreciate your help

Comment: Try adding the argument `na.rm = TRUE` to your `melt` call.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thats it! Thank you so much!!! Just out of curiosity, you mentioned using a filter. How would you do that in the melt function? lets say if you want to remove a certain value (f.e. empty or a certain symbol like "-") instead of NA (since you have no specific possibility to ignore as you can with na.rm = TRUE)? If you don't mind helping more :)

Comment: Not within the melt function, filtering would be a separate step. If you have symbols like `-` that should be treated as `NA`, that's a problem to solve earlier in your script. Most functions for reading in data have an argument called `na.strings` or similar that lets you configure which values should be treated as `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not `melt` the `NA` values, set `na.rm = TRUE` inside the `melt()` function.

```
MTA_data.long <-melt(MTA_data,id.vars = "ReportingDates", na.rm = TRUE)

x <- ggplot(MTA_data.long, aes(ReportingDates, value, color = variable)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = variable)) +
    geom_point()
```

As a side note, you don't need to re-specify the data and aesthetics set in `ggplot()`. They will be inherited by subsequent layers.